# Testing against engine routes in Rails with Test::Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, spree, testunit

I am trying to make some functional tests against new functionality in an application that uses [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree).

The problem that I am running into is that when I launch my created test, the path variables that should exists are not there for the test to execute.

Say I have these routes in my local `routes.rb`:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
    namespace :admin do
      resources :image_games
    end
  end
```

Now in my test I would have the following:

```
require 'test_helper'

module Spree
  module Admin
    class ImageGamesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
      test 'Should get index' do
        get admin_image_games_path
        assert_response :success
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What happens is that a `Minitest::UnexpectedError: NameError: undefined local variable or method`admin_image_games_path'` error will be thrown.

I found some advice about this but all of the solutions seem to be for RSpec. I would like to keep using Test::Unit as I feel more at home with it.

So my question, how to load in routes from a foreign Rails Engine into functional tests?

EDIT:

It seems that just the helpers are not working for my tests.
Using `get '/store/admin/image_games'` works but `get admin_image_games_path` does not. When running the application normally then these helpers do work tough.

Comment: Don't your path needs any parameter?

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata I do need to log in the user but other than that no. The index does not take parameters.

Comment: Just to make sure, when you do `bundle exec rake routes` your path appears in the list just like you're using it?

Comment: Yes, admin_image_games GET                       /admin/image_games(.:format)                                                  spree/admin/image_games#index

Comment: When you change the `get` specifying the controller like this: `get :index`, does it work?

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata It will give a `Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"spree/admin/image_games"}`

I declare the routes for this controller in Spree engine block so I imagine it's not loaded at that point. When not using the tests then the routes work.